# Trim the second word to its First letter using css/js

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following div. The text in it will be dynamic.

```
<div class="full_name">Libin Babu</div>
```

And I want the result as `Libin B.`

That is I want to TRIM the second name to its first letter and followed by a "dot".
Any help with CSS or jQuery?? I prefer a css solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to replace `Libin Babu` text with `Libin B.` inside that `<div>`?

Comment: @andyb Yeah. Exactly!

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use replace/regex:

```
"Libin Babu".replace(/^(\S+)\s+(\S).*/, '$1 $2.')
// "Libin B."
```

To replace it in place, you could use:

```
$('.full_name').each(function (d, div) {
    $(div).text($(div).text().replace(/^(\S+)\s+(\S).*/, '$1 $2.'));
});
```

Regex explanation:

```
/          // Regex start
  ^        // Beggining of the string
  (\S+)    // One or more non-whitespace characters in group $1
  \s+      // One or more whitespace characters
  (\S)     // Exactly one non-whitespace character in group $2
  .*       // Any number of any characters
/          // Regex end
```

Comment: Perfect! That works. Waiting if anyone come up with a CSS solution. :)

Comment: I think i'm happy with the regex!!! =) You are amazing @kamituel. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Libin - no problem :) you got me thinking on doing this in CSS, though. Wonder if anyone would came up with such a thing.

Comment: a small help. How to trim other words after the 2nd word? If the div contain `Libin Babu word` , your result will append the 3rd word as well. But I want the result till the first letter of second word.

Comment: @Libin - just replace last `\S*` with `.*` - see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = $('#div').text();
var ret = str.split(" ");
your required value = ret[0] + ' ' + ret[1].charAt(0);
```

However you will need to validate if the second string length is >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use java script substring. example. 

Script (place this in header section)
-----------------------------
<script language="javascript">
    function splitword(word){
        var your_str = word;
        var str1 = your_str.substr(0,your_str.indexOf(' '));
        var str2 = your_str.substr(your_str.indexOf(' ')+1);
        var str2 = str2.substr(0,1);    
        alert(str1+" "+str2+".");   
    }
</script>


HTML (place this in body section)
--------------------------------
<div class="full_name">Libin Babu</div>
<input type="button" value="Split" onclick="splitword('Libin Babu');" />
```